# C# MVVM добавить объекта в модель

Tags: c#, исключения, mvvm

Здраствуйте, не могу разобраться с добавлением объекта в Model.

```
namespace SnakeGame.Model
{
[DataContract]
public class DataModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public static string DataPath = "score.dat";
    public DataModel()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>()
        {
            new Player() {Score = 133, Name = "Ivan", Number = 6, Status = Player.ScoreStatus.Use}
        };
    }

    public static DataModel Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(DataPath)) return DataSerializer.DeserializeItem(DataPath);
        return new DataModel();
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        DataSerializer.SerializeData(DataPath,this);
    }
}
}
```

Далее на кнопку добавление нового игрока, я делаю так.

```
 public partial class AddUserControll : UserControl
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public static DataModel _model;
    public static DataViewModel _viewModel;
    public static string namePlayer;
    private int count = 5;
    public AddUserControll()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        namePlayer = name.Text;
        var tmp = new Player()
        {
            Score = 0,
            Name = namePlayer,
            Number = count,
            Status = Player.ScoreStatus.Use
        };
        _model.Players.Add(tmp);
        count++;
        try
        {
            _model = Mapper.Map<DataViewModel, DataModel>(_viewModel);
            _model.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Вылезает System.NullReferenceException

По MVVM все должно быть правильно, все View наследуются ViewModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: А что есть `[DataMember]`? Вы пользуетесь каким-то фреймворком?

Comment: [DataMember] используется для сериализации, он лежит в System.Runtime.Serialization;

Comment: Ну допустим. А почему у вас вдруг View знает про модель (в `button_Click` лежит `DataModel _model`)? Это не по MVVM-овски.

Comment: Ну и в какой строчке у вас `NullReferenceException`? Покажите call stack.

Comment: Да, так и есть. А каким тогда образом можна впихнуть в ту модель нового игрока?

Comment: _model.Players.Add(tmp); - тут вылетает

Comment: Ну, вы же пишете на MVVM, да? В MVVM так не делают.

Comment: Окей, а чему равен в этот момент `_model` и `_model.Players`? Похоже, у вас `_model == null`.

Comment: тут просто много кода, я незнаю как правильно его показать весь

Comment: Та и я понял что тут неправильный подход. Нужно другой стороной идти

Comment: В MVVM, для справки, View вовсе не знает о модели, а ссылки на VM имеет в идеале только в DataContext. Ну и ни в коем случае не создаёт себе VM, а наоборот, получает VM снаружи.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/PavloSerdyuk/videos канал моего преподавателя

Comment: Сейчас у вас `_model == null`. Вам нужно инициализировать `_model`, например, в конструкторе `_model = new DataModel();`. А вообще, как сказал выше @VladD, правильнее будет унести ее в VM, т.к. View не должна знать о моделях.

Comment: Там есть курс с 8 видео, там и будет конкретный пример, с одного видео не получится

Comment: @AlekseyBichuk поищите на торрентах уроки от "Pluralsign" по WPF&MVVM, там хоть и на английском, но с понятными схемами, что и как показано, надеюсь тогда вы сможете разобраться. Я посмотрел, то что ваш препод показывал, но, такую кашу из наслоений классов, без толкового объяснения для чего и почему, понять не возможно, зачем то ему понадобился мэпер, вьюмодели упоковал в коллекции... бррр!

Comment: @AlekseyBichuk я в свое время на скорую руку набросал проект, для примера посмотрите, пожалуйста, там нет ничего сложного одно окно, одна ViewModel и простейшая коллекция объектов. Надеюсь, вам поможет кое-что понять... [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/ud7mV3Fbwqr6G)

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо